3D Model's Base Color Showing as Black on Three.js Site
I was finally got my model to show up and now the the textures aren't showing correctly. Anybody know what's going wrong?
Code Live View next to 3D Model in Blender:

// Load HDR environment map
let envmaploader = new THREE.PMREMGenerator(renderer);
new RGBELoader().setPath('/models/Magic8Ball/textures/').load('/industrial_sunset_puresky_8k.hdr', function(hdrmap) {
    let envmap = envmaploader.fromCubemap(hdrmap).texture;

    // Magic 8 Ball material setup
    const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        map: tilesbasecolor,
        normalMap: tilesnormalMap,
        displacementMap: tilesheightMap,
        displacementScale: 0.08,
        roughnessMap: tilesroughnessMap,
        roughness: 1,
        aoMap: tilesambientOcclusionMap,
        metalnessMap: tilesmetallic,
        metalness: 0.8,
        envMap: envmap // Use the generated envmap
    });

    // Load GLTF model
    loader.load(
        'scene.gltf',
        function(gltf) {
            let object = gltf.scene;
            object.traverse(function(child) {
                if (child.isMesh) {
                    child.material = material; // Assign the material to all meshes in the model
                }
            });
            scene.add(object);
            object.scale.set(100, 100, 100); // Scale the model
        },
        function(xhr) {
            console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded');
        },
        function(error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    );
});

      //8 Ball Texture
      const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
      const tilesbasecolor = textureLoader.load("./models/Magic8Ball/textures/Diffuse.png");
      const tilesnormalMap = textureLoader.load("./models/Magic8Ball/textures/Magic8Ball_Normal_v2.png");
      const tilesheightMap = textureLoader.load("./models/Magic8Ball/textures/Magic8Ball_Bump_v2.png");
      const tilesroughnessMap = textureLoader.load("./models/Magic8Ball/textures/Magic8Ball_Roughness_v2.png");
      const tilesambientOcclusionMap = textureLoader.load("./models/Magic8Ball/textures/Magic8Ball_Glossiness_v2.png");
      const tilesmetallic = textureLoader.load("./models/Magic8Ball/textures/Magic8Ball_Metalness_v2.png");

      const loader = new GLTFLoader().setPath('models/Magic8ball/');

I've tried re-exporting the textures and the gilf file.

Hi, loading texture is async operation and you not waiting for load end. So i think textures not exist when you creating material. Thats why it's black. Try use three js developer tools for chrome to check material data.
